# Surface power supply with a USB charging port flickering on mobile

Tags: usb, power, microsoft-surface-pro, usb-3.1-type-c

According to this link
https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-au/support/hardware-and-drivers/battery-and-power?os=windows-10&=undefined#USB10
I can connect my Moto to be charged via the USB port on the power supply. Moto has a  Type C Usb Charging cable.

But when I do, the charging signal on the mobile **flickers** in a regular manner (showing the charging symbol for a snap of a second, then non-charging for a second). The charge never builds up. What does that mean?

Comment: What is power rating on the charger you are using? Do you have the Surface plugged in as well as your Moto, at the same time?

Comment: Not sure, it has two values: 12V at 2.58 A, and 5V at 1A. I tried with the surface plugged or unplugged, same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From web search, I believe you have the Surface dedicated AC-DC adapter. One output (12V 2.58A) goes to proprietary cable to the laptop. The other output has Type-A receptacle, rated for standard 5 V 1 A.

I think that your Moto phone has illegal Type-C to Type-A charging cable made for the Moto dedicated charger, which likely has higher (>1 A) power rating. Type-A connector doesn't have means to report its power capability over Type-C charging cable, so the original rating must be advertised in Type-C cable overmold.

I believe your phone tries to get more power (2.1 A?) than the Surface port can provide, voltage sags, the phone tries to reduce consumption, but the control range is likely insufficient, so it drops the charge process, then tries again. This process keeps the screen on most of the time and therefore uses up a good part of the energy (might be less, might be more) that the phone can charge in the short timespan current is flowing.

The Type-A port on the Surface ACDC must have some other charging signature, BC1.2, PD1.0 or else. It is difficult to say why your Moto phone failed to recognize this without exact details of your phone.